# White background in icon for Google Search on mobile device

Tags: android, marketing, google-play

We experience an issue with our game icon related to google search on mobile device. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, our ccon has a white background on a green wall. We are aware that we have to use a 512x512 PNG with alpha channel.

The shown image is a 80x80 JPG which is, I guess, created out of our icon by using some background color. Could it be that we have to set this color somewere in the store or maybe in the app manifest?

Thanks for you help in advance ;)